We have problem w Tab in our application?
we have problem with tab in our application.
In the application manifest we only have a link to Microsoft Forms.
Json:
{
            "entityId": "Zaraportuj",
            "name": "Zaraportuj",
            "contentUrl": "in here we have only url",
            "websiteUrl": "in here we have only url",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ],
            "context": [
                "personalTab"
            ]
        }

And that's it. On the code side, we do not manage this tab in any way. Everything is in the manifest.
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
I didn't try anything special. I changed Microsoft Forms and added a new Forms but no changes.
Any solution ? Why isn't the Microsoft Forms tab showing? ?

Could you please confirm if you have added the URL in the validDomains section of the manifest?

No, cause i received validation report with this: "App includes domains that are not owned by the App/Partner in Valid Domain section."

@Nivedipa-MSFT any solution  ?

The only supported way to embed Forms content into Teams is via the built-in Forms app. You cannot embed Form UI in custom app as a Tab.

